# how to change my username (the name left of the cursor) in a new linux install?

Tags: linux, command-line, amazon-ec2

I'm not sure how to search for this because I don't know the terminology. How can I change the username that appears left of the cursor in my Linux install? Right now, I'm running an Amazon EC2 instance and there is a long username to the left of my cursor when I'm entering commands.

```
[root@ip-12-34-56-789 /etc]#
```

So it shows my user name, my IP address (why?) and the directory I'm currently in... I only really want to see the username, or nothing at all actually.

- How can I change this setting?
- What is the correct terminology I can use to describe this area to the left of my cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PS1 shell variable is used to set it [see](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). (Search PS1). Try typing `export PS1='\u$'` on the shell and pressing enter. To make it persistent across the sessions you might need to add it to the bashrc file(~/.bashrc)